# add int to certain string python

Tags: python, sympy

I have a list containing many different types and sympy symbols, and I would like to add an int to a specific symbol within the list.

i.e if my list were:

```
 [-2*c_0*y_0*(y_0 - 1),
  -2*c_0*(-y_0**2 + yx1*(y_0**2/yx1 + 1)), 
  +2*c_1*(0.5*c_2 - 0.5*y_0) + 0.1, 4*c_0*y_0**2, 
  -8*c_0*y_0*(-y_0**2 + yx1*(y_0**2/yx1 + 1))]
```

How can I construct a for loop such that every `y_0` has an int value added to it?

Many thanks

Comment: "I have a list [...]" - I suppose you mean `string` and not `list`?

Comment: Okay I have added square brackets if you are unable to process the world "list."

Comment: Well, it's a list of strings, right? Show the actual code.

Comment: y_0 is a sympy symbol

Comment: and why don't you state that in your question? Could you give **all** relevant information and give a code example that we can reproduce? Well, all the basics for asking... I still can't read minds!

Comment: @user1987097 Well that's obviously relevant information. You should add that to the question. And check out [the sympy docs](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/index.html).

Comment: It is stated in my question.

Comment: @user1987097 I was unable to process your question because it was poorly asked - you shoud have mentioned sympy from the beginning because the question was very ambiguous without this information.

Comment: The question does begin with "I have a list containing many different types and *sympy symbols*", and states that the user wants to add the int "to a specific *symbol*".  Not sure what's so unclear about that.

Comment: @JustinSBarrett the word `sympy` was just added by OP in an edit, before it just said `symbols`...

Comment: but amongst the things that are missing (or missed), the OP does not give what he already tried, if he has any error...

Answer (score 0):

well, I just read the [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers) and found out that you can just do:

```
y_0 = y_0 + 1
```

just before your equation, and you're all set...